# is it possible to display string through tooltip using a html.textareafor.

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to build a view using MVC and i will be using a html.textareafor and I wanna know if I will be able to use a tooltip on this html.textareafor before entering a string.

Comment: Anything is possible.  What have you tried?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: If you need customized CSS Tooltip for TextArea - http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Tooltip-Plugin-for-jQuery-tooltip-js/

Answer (score 0):

HTML tooltips are derived from the `title` attribute, are they not?  You can [add custom HTML attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703546.aspx) to your helpers:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SomeValue, new { title = model.SomeTooltipValue })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TextBoxFor and you will be able to pass custom attribute values via anonmous object

the html helper @title="help" will do the trick

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new {@title="help text"})
```

Please look at this link.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024563/html-helper-add-tooltip-to-textboxfor)